# MouseListener Not Responding

Tags: java, mouseevent, awt, mouselistener

I can't get this `MouseListener` to work.  Why?  Nothing happens when I click th mouse

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/** Draws an oval whenever the user clicks the mouse */
public class DrawOvals extends GraphicsProgram implements MouseListener {
  public void run() {
    addMouseListener(this);
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    GOval oval = new GOval(100,100,OVAL_SIZE, OVAL_SIZE);
    oval.setFilled(true);
    add(oval, e.getX(), e.getY());
    System.out.println("Got here!");
  }

  /* Private constants */
  private static final double OVAL_SIZE = 20;

  /* implements the required methods for mouse listener*/
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is the symptom?

Comment: Does the mouseClicked method get called?  Try putting a System.out.println("Got here!") in the method to see.

Comment: @Roy.  When I click the mouse on the graphics window, nothing happens.  I did as you suggested and nothing gets printed on the console either, so I guess the mouseClicked method is not getting called.

Comment: are you calling `run()` anywhere? If not, none of these will work...

Comment: @Jon  I am a student of Java.  We are told to use run() as the starting method and Eclipse will execute that as the starting point of the class.  It works on several other programs I've written.

Comment: Can you add the source of `GraphicsProgram` in your question?

Comment: Also, add a print statment in run() and let's see if what you were told is true.

Comment: @Sérgio Michels No I cannot because it is part of a package I'm using.  The description is here http://jtf.acm.org/rationale/program-package.html  this also explains the use of the run() and init() methods.  BTW I have never been able to get init() working so I've abandoned it.  Compiler complains that I'm trying to overwrite a final method in Program.

Comment: `run()` is not automatically called. The correct method name would be `public static void main(String[] args)`. That will be called automatically.

Answer (score 1):

According to the link you provided in the comments in the OP, you have to call

```
addMouseListeners();
```

instead of

```
addMouseListener(this);
```

The description says:
"Use the GraphicsProgram itself as a listener for mouse events that occur within the embedded GCanvas. To do so, all the student has to do is define any listener methods to which the program needs to respond and then call addMouseListeners(), which registers the program as both a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener."

The other option is to use

```
GCanvas canvas = getGCanvas();
canvas.addMouseListener(this);
```